# Adding more than one perform click in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add 2 consecutive perform click in android studio but whenever I run the application and reach the point of the 2 perform clicks the application crashes.

```
if (showFirstLetter == true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                    doneButton.performClick();
                    resetButton.performClick();

                }
            }
```

Comment: please share the crash log along with the code, so that it can be helpful for debug the cause,

Comment: I am getting this message when the app crashes:

Comment: A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 12949